# Multiple t.references get nil with nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Devise for users.

**User.rb**

```
belongs_to shop
has_many tasks
```

**Show.rb**

```
has_many users
has_many tasks
```

**Task.rb**

```
belongs_to user
belongs_to shop
```

when I create a new task:

```
current_user.tasks.create(...)
```

the `shop_id` gets the value of nil, when I need to be the same `shop_id` as the user.

when I create a new task

```
  current_user.shop.tasks.create(...)
```

I get the user_id as nil but gets the right value for the `shop_id`.

what am I am missing?

thanks in advance.

Comment: did u try to run in `rails console` ?

Comment: yup, same results.

Comment: can u try this one  `User.first.tasks.create(...)` ?

Comment: This works now somehow ... !!!!!
Post it as an answer or something, I will mark it up.

Comment: This works now somehow in the console only, weird!

Answer (score 0):

When

```
current_user.tasks.create(...)
```

is run rails association would not know that it has to populated shop_id unless you explicitly send it

```
current_user.tasks.create(shop_id: current_user.shop.id)
```

Same the other way around. You can use a better modeling for this case with polymorphic association between user, shops and tasks. More details and example can be found here.

See
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Do not think this is related to devise.

Answer (score 0):

In `current_user.shop.tasks.create(...)` you're calling `create` directly on the `tasks` collection for a singular `shop`. This is effectively equivalent to:

```
Shop.find_by(user_id: current_user.id).tasks.create(...)
```

Shops can possibly have more than one user, so there's nothing explicit in that statement that the newly created task should belong to `current_user`.

I think the simplest solution is to create the task by itself, explicitly setting both foreign keys:

```
Task.create(shop_id: current_user.shop_id, user_id: current_user.id)
```

Though you'd have to reload your `user` and `shop` references to pick up the newly associated `task`.

If you want something more automatic, consider using an association callback on  `has_many :tasks` within user where `shop_id` for a `Task` is set from the `user`'s shop_id:

```
class user < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  has_many :tasks, before_add: :assign_to_shop

  def assign_to_shop(task)
    task.shop = self.shop
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Devise `current_user` method returns same object of user.

```
# simple example
  def sign_in 
    session[:current_user] = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  end

  def current_user
   session[:current_user]
  end
```

If user signed in, then `current_user` method should work, as like in right below.

```
#1
current_user.tasks.create(...)

#2 you can also like this
t = Task.new(...)
t.user_id = current_user.id
t.save
```

You can play in `rails console`, easy to understand it.

```
current_user = User.first
current_user.tasks.create(...)
```

Comment: I changed nothing, this worked on console only, and somehow it stopped. I know this sounds crazy, but thats right!

Comment: @KamalG'ool Did u sign in ?

Comment: I did, I fixed that in the controllers, every time creating, assigning shop and user according to current_user, I will post an answer later on.